# In 2 Timothy 1:7 what is a "spirit of fear"?

Tags: pneumatology, 2-timothy, spirit

> KJV 2 Timothy 1:7  For God hath not given us **the spirit of fear**;
>   but of power, and of love, and of a sound mind.

Also, it appears that the "spirit of fear" is what was NOT given and that what WAS provided was a "spirit of power, a spirit of love and a spirit of a sound mind".

Does this present us with an odd anatomy? Metaphor?

Comment: These are descriptions of what the Spirit is and is not rather than individual spirits.

Comment: "The spirit of fear" is what the Spirit is not.  "Of power" and "of love" is what the Spirit is.

Comment: @Ruminator - refer to our previous discussion about the shades of meaning for "spirit" being tinged with the concept of a person's attitude or disposition; and that such a personal attitude may originate from the Holy spirit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although δειλία does possess some connotations of fear, it more resembles the English word “cowardice.” Thus, BDAG,<sup>1</sup>

[image: BDAG, p. 215, δειλία]

Philo explicitly states that ἀνδρεία, meaning “courage,”<sup>2</sup> and δειλία are opposite qualities.<sup>3</sup>

[image: Philo, De Opificio Mundi, Vol. 1, p. 25, §737]

The apostle Paul seems to allude to the Holy Spirit when he wrote that God has not given Christians the spirit of cowardice. In his epistle to the Corinthians, Paul commands the Corinthians,<sup>4</sup>

> <sup>13</sup> “Watch! Stand fast in the faith! Be courageous! Be strong!”
>
> <sup>ΙΓʹ</sup> γρηγορεῖτε στήκετε ἐν τῇ πίστει ἀνδρίζεσθε κραταιοῦσθε

The last imperative, “Be strong!” is translated from the verb κραταιόω. The apostle Paul only uses this verb once elsewhere, in the following passage:

> <sup>16</sup> that He would grant you, according to the riches of His glory, **to be strengthened** with might **through His Spirit** in the inner man,

This seems to suggest that it is the Holy Spirit that strengthens Christians and thus causes them to be courageous.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> BDAG, p. 215, δειλία
<sup>2</sup> Mantzouranis, p. [163](https://books.google.com/books?id=cMOvDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>3</sup> *De Opificio Mundi* (“On the Creation of the World”), Vol. 1, p. [25](https://archive.org/details/philonisalexandr0103philuoft/page/n148), §73; also, cf. *De mutatione nominum* (“On the Change of Names”), Vol. 3, p. [190](https://archive.org/details/philonisalexandr0103philuoft/page/190), §197; *De Legum Allegoriae I* (“Allegorical Interpretation, I”), Vol. 1, p. [78](https://archive.org/details/philonisalexandr0103philuoft/page/n200), §65
<sup>4</sup> 1 Cor. 16:13

#### References

Arndt, William; Bauer, Walter; Danker, Frederick William. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4gyfDwAAQBAJ) 3rd ed. Chicago: U of Chicago P, 2000.

Philo of Alexandria. [*Philonis Alexandrini Opera Quae Supersunt.*](https://archive.org/details/philonisalexandr0103philuoft/) Ed. Cohn, Leopold; Wendland, Paulus. Vol. 1–3. Berlin: Reimeri, 1896–1898.

Mantzouranis, Kleanthis. “A Philoshopical Reception of Homer: Homeric Courage in Aristotle’s Discussion of ἀνδρεία.” [*Homeric Receptions Across Generic and Cultural Contexts.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cMOvDAAAQBAJ) Ed. Efstathiou, Athanasios; Karamanou, Ioanna. Berlin: de Gruyter, 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Romans 8:15 ([ESV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208%3A15&version=ESV)

15 For you did not receive the spirit of slavery to fall back into fear, but you have received the Spirit of adoption as sons, by whom we cry, “Abba! Father!”

Hebrews 2:14-15 ([ESV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%202%3A14-15&version=ESV)

14 Since therefore the children share in flesh and blood, he himself likewise partook of the same things, that through death he might destroy the one who has the power of death, that is, the devil, 15 and deliver all those who through fear of death were subject to lifelong slavery.

It seems to me that the spirit of fear from 2 Timothy 1:7 should be juxtaposed against the "Spirit of adoption" from Romans 8:15. The spirit of fear is then a spirit of slavery, and that slavery is then, a fear of death, or more rightly, the fear of the power of death, over which the Devil held sway. Therefore the spirit of fear from 2 Timothy 1:7 is a devilish spirit whereby one is re-enslaved to the Devil and made to fear death and its power once more.

As such, it is the fear of falling back into the family and being under the fatherhood of, Satan.

Put simply, then, it is unbelief (Note the  "Cowardly, and the faithless" from [Revelation 21:8 ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021%3A8&version=ESV), and how these, among others, become subject to the Second Death).